# Google Recaptcha Gateway timedout exception

Tags: java, jboss, recaptcha

I am having a issue with the integrated Google Recaptcha, as on submitting the request I am getting a "gateway timedout exception". This is mainly because our Application server (Jboss 4.2) is not able to receive a valid response from the Google server.

Googles Recaptcha states that "Google not frequently but occasionally" keeps changing the IP address and has issue with Java's JVM. And to fix this we need to refresh the DNS cache.

One suggestion given by Google is to set the ttl to 30 sec (which is definitely an overhead on our application servers to refresh the DNS cache every 30 secs) or restart JVM (which is not possible as its the production server).

If anybody could suggest how to clear the JVM DNS cache manually without restarting the JBoss application server or by means of console would be most appreciated.

Comment: Ask this question on ServerFault for a (better) response.

Comment: Okay, may be I can frame it better. How to clear the JVM DNS cache without restarting it !

Comment: No, post this on www.serverfault.com

Comment: thanks Telthien, the issue got resolved as Google Recaptcha keeps changing the IP address on occasional basis. We had to open some range of ipAdress for recaptcha to work